# How to detect patch in front of turtle in Netlogo 3D

Tags: netlogo

I'm making a driving simulation in Netlogo 3D, and I want the car to "crash" and become the shape "fire" when it hits the side of the garage made out of colored patches that are a different color than the car and the ground. Its there a way for the turtle to detect the garage and "crash"?

Answer (score 0):

[`patch-ahead`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-ahead) should work in 3D.